# Julia Quick way to initialise an empty array that's the same size as another?

Tags: arrays, initialization, julia

I have an array

```
array1 = Array{Int,2}(undef, 2, 3)
```

Is there a way to quickly make a new array that's the same size as the first one? E.g. something like

```
array2 = Array{Int,2}(undef, size(array1))
```

current I have to do this which is pretty cumbersome, and even worse for higher dimension arrays

```
array2 = Array{Int,2}(undef, size(array1)[1], size(array1)[2])
```

Comment: The best solution is `similar`, but didn't you try your own suggestion? `Array{Int,2}(undef, size(array1))` works just fine!

Comment: It works but you have to type a lot. Lots and lots if you're working with multiple-multi-dimentional arrays that you have to preallocate hah.

Comment: No, I'm saying that `Array{Int,2}(undef, size(array1))` works, while you said it didn't. It works for _all_ dimensionalities.

Comment: Aaarg, I meant `Array{Int}(undef, size(array1))`. OK, now I see the problem: The number 2 inside the type parameter. Take it away, and it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is `similar(array1)`.

You can even change up the array type by passing in a type, e.g.

```
similar(array1, Float64)
similar(array1, Int64)
```

Comment: Glad to help! It also works for structured arrays, ie `similar(sparseMatrix)` has the same sparsity pattern.

Comment: I also realised that you can change the type of the similar() array as well! Will edit your answer

Comment: You can also keep the type and change the size.

Answer (score 2):

Using `similar` is a great solution. But the reason your original attempt doesn't work is the number 2 in the type parameter signature: `Array{Int, 2}`. The number 2 specifies that the array must have 2 dimensions. If you remove it you can have exactly as many dimensions as you like:

```
julia> a = rand(2,4,3,2);

julia> b = Array{Int}(undef, size(a));

julia> size(b)
(2, 4, 3, 2)
```

This works for other array constructors too:

```
zeros(size(a))
ones(size(a))
fill(5, size(a))
# etc.
```

Comment: Ahh i see that makes sense as well! I guess both are equally valid, this method is a bit more explicit in what you're asking for, probably clearer to the reader